# How can I find out in Java if a PDF file contains a JBIG2 image?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, jbig2

I am using Apache PDFBox to read a PDF file and convert it into a JPEG image.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
...

byte[] fileBytes;
...
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes));
BufferedImage image = new PDFRenderer(pdDocument).renderImage(0);
pdDocument.close();
```

Sometimes the PDF document contains JBIG2 images. I am using the [JBIG2 ImageIO Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/jbig2-imageio) for PDFBox to correctly process such PDF documents. This works fine. But I would like to know after the conversion whether the orignal PDF document contained a JBIG2 image or not.

I checked the [PDDocument Javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html), but I cannot figure out a way to answer this seemingly simple question: **Does a given PDF document contain at least one JBIG2 image or not?**

Since I am already using PDFBox, a solution with the means of PDFBox would be preferred, but other suggestions would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get the source code of `ExtractImages.java` from the source code download or from [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java?view=markup). Search for this line in the `write2file` method:

```
String suffix = pdImage.getSuffix();
```

now add some code like

```
if ("jb2".equals(suffix))
{
    // do your stuff here, i.e. remember that it is JBIG2
}
```

then remove all the rest from that method.